# javascript working in an opposite manner

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to use a "select" list along with javascript. I did a Javascript function that hide or show parts of html code but it's working in the opposite way and i can't figure out where I went wrong coz the code seems to be straight forward.

my JS function is

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       


    function toggle(id) {

        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='IELTS' || document.getElementById(id).value=='TOEFL')
        {
            if(document.getElementById('dv1').style.display=='block')
            {
                document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='hidden';
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='visible';
            //alert('Its displaying now');
        }


        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='Other')
        {
            if(document.getElementById('dv2').style.display=='block')
            {
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='hidden';
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='visible';
        }


        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='none')
        {
                document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='hidden';
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='hidden';
        }



    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the FIRST "if" statement is showing/hiding "dv2" instead of "dv1" and the SECOND "if" statement is showing/hiding "dv1" instead of "dv2" although everything is specified such a way that the FIRST "if" statement handles "dv1" and the SECOND "if" statement handles "dv2"

Am I missing something in the way of understanding of how JS works..

Here a style is predefined to make the html code hidden

```
<style type="text/css">
.toggleClass{
    display:none; 
    visibility:hidden;
    } 
</style>
</head>



<body>

<form name="myform" >
```

this is the select where i called the JS function upon change

```
    <select id="exam" name="exam" onchange="toggle('exam')">
    <option selected="selected" value="none" >Please Choose</option>
    <option value="IELTS">IELTS</option>
    <option value="TOEFL">TOEFL</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>   
  <br><br>
```

this is dv1

```
<div id="dv1" class="toggleClass">
    <table width="50%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="600" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">IELTS and TOEFL</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is dv2

```
<div id="dv2" class="toggleClass">
    <table width="50%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="600" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Other</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

note that it works fine if I swap "dv1" and "dv2"!

Comment: Could you pls fiddle it ? Its too long it would be great to see the code out on Fiddle.

Comment: ok i removed all my comments in the javascript function in order for it to be presented as one chunk, is that better?

Comment: give me a min.Thanks ll go through!!

Comment: just a note: a property of style is set only if there is (in html code) an inline style of this property.

Comment: can you use jQuery or other JS libs?

Comment: well if jQuery works fine I won't mind but this one is really working fine if it wasn't for that small issue. i would try jQuery, I'm using WAMP for php and mysql

Comment: In addition to @chumkiu's comment: If you wish the default style to be applied, then set the value to an empty string, rather than what you think the default value is.  E.g. instead of `style.display = 'block'`, just say `style.display=''` - that way the browser will revert back to whatever has been specified in your CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this block of code:-

```
if(document.getElementById(id).value=='Other')
        {
            if(document.getElementById('dv2').style.display=='block')
            {
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='hidden';
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='visible';
        }
```

It is evident from here that if you are selecting the 'Other' then in such a case div two will never appear. Because the condition is true where as the else condition mentioned below :-

```
else 
        {
            document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='visible';
            //alert('Its displaying now');
        }
```

will display the div1 as you have validated.The script you are seeking for must be like this mentioned below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       


    function toggle(id) {

        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='IELTS' || document.getElementById(id).value=='TOEFL')
        {
            if(document.getElementById('dv1').style.display=='block')
            {
               document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='visible';

            }
        }
        else 
        {
```

document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='none';

```
            document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='hidden';
            //alert('Its displaying now');
        }


        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='Other')
        {
            if(document.getElementById('dv2').style.display=='block')
            {
                document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='block';
               document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='visible';
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('dv2').style.visibility='hidden';

        }


        if(document.getElementById(id).value=='none')
        {
                document.getElementById('Table1').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('Table1').style.visibility='hidden';
                document.getElementById('Table2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('Table2').style.visibility='hidden';
        }



    }
</script>
```

try this out and leme know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST: the property of style is set only if there is a inline style of this property.

so in your div you should insert a style attribute

```
<div id="dv1" class="toggleClass" style="visibility:hidden; display:none">
```

the same for div2

After that... the logical seems not correct:

```
if(document.getElementById(id).value=='IELTS' || document.getElementById(id).value=='TOEFL')
```

this line should be visible the first div (`div1`) but after this:

```
document.getElementById('dv1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('dv1').style.visibility='hidden';
```

you hide it!